# How to get the items around a specific item?

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to get x items before and y items after (the neighbors of) the record with `"lastseen":true`:

```
// (_id fields omitted)
{ "msg": "hello 1" }
{ "msg": "hello 2" }
{ "msg": "hello 3", "lastseen": true }
{ "msg": "hello 4" }
{ "msg": "hello 5" }
```

For example, if I query with `x=1` and `y=1` the result should be:

```
// (_id fields omitted)
{ "msg": "hello 2" }
{ "msg": "hello 3", "lastseen": true }
{ "msg": "hello 4" }
```

What are my options in mongodb to achieve that?

Comment: Are these individual documents or subdocuments within a document?

Comment: Individual, no sub/embedded documents

Answer (score 1):

It must be simpler to implement the logic on client side with several queries. Assuming you documents are ordered by _id:

- `findOne({"lastseen":true})`
- `find({_id: {$lt: <_id from the previous query>}}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)`
- `find({_id: {$gt: <_id from the first query>}}).sort({_id:1}).limit(1)`

The only way to do it in a single query I can imagine is to group the documents into array, and then use [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html) in combination with [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // ensure lastseen is present to calculate index properly
    { $addFields: {lastseen: { $ifNull: [ "$lastseen", false ] } } },
    // get all documents into array
    { $group: { _id:null, docs: { $push:"$$ROOT" } } },
    // get index of first matched document
    { $project: { docs:1, match: { $indexOfArray: [ "$docs.lastseen", true ] } } },
    // slice the array
    { $project: { docs: { $slice: [ "$docs", { $subtract: [ "$match", 1 ] } , 3 ] } } },
    // remove added lastseen
    { $project: { docs:
        { $map: {
           input: "$docs",
           as: "doc",
           in: { $cond: { 
               if: "$$doc.lastseen", 
               then: "$$doc", 
               else: { $arrayToObject: { $filter: { 
                   input: { $objectToArray: "$$doc" }, 
                   as: "field", 
                   cond: { $ne: [ "$$field.k", "lastseen" ] } 
               } } }
           } }
        } }
    } },
    // un-group documents from the array
    { $unwind: "$docs" },
    { $replaceRoot: {newRoot:"$docs"}}
 ]);
```

but I doubt efficiency of such query.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very short you can use skip() to skip how many you want
// (_id fields omitted)

{ "msg": "hello 1" }

{ "msg": "hello 2" }`

{ "msg": "hello 3", "lastseen": true }

{ "msg": "hello 4" }

{ "msg": "hello 5" }

**Command:**
db.collection.find({},{_id:0}).skip(1)